# Mobile Angular UI bootstrap theme

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, mobile-angular-ui

I'm nearing the end of my first big mobile angular project.
Thus far I've just adopted default styles from the twitter bootstrap provided,  bootstrap style sheet links look like this:

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/toaster.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/mobile-angular-ui-hover.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/mobile-angular-ui-base.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/mobile-angular-ui-desktop.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

What should be my next steps to restyle default fonts, colors etc.

So for example, this style is set in the mobile-angular-ui-base css:
`.text-primary{color:#007aff;}`

In the bootstrap css I like has it defined as:
`.text-primary{color:#b58900}`

So if I want to inherit the theme / styles from the bootstrap is it just a matter of creating a further custom css superceding the styles again?

Or is there some way of regenerating the mobile angular css based on a bootstrap?

Comment: do you want to do this for all or just for particular text?

Comment: Hi - yes I want to do this for all. I note the bootstrap styles are superceded by the mobile angular css stylesheet. So obviously I cant just pull in a new bootstrap with the look and feel I like.

Comment: do you any custom stylesheet for your project?

Comment: I have some custom styling, but have tried to stick with fundamental bootstap classes like 'text-success' or 'btn-primary' again in the hope that i would be able to experiment with different bootstraps at the end of the development cycle

Comment: jut add  a custom css and add styles to it to override bootstrap styles..thats the only way

Comment: hi thanks - i was beginning to suspect as much - i feel there's scope for a utility here to improve the styling capabilities of mobile-angular!!